# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, math, calculator, typeerror

So I'm working on a project where we need to have four different calculators, in JavaScript: Loan Term, Loan Qualifier, Loan Repayment, and Loan Amount. I have had so much trouble with these. 
As of now I have the first two working okay (Loan Term and Loan Qualifier). The other two simply do nothing, even though I haven't touched the code from how it was on the original website (this project is a website redesign). 
The only thing that I could catch, with Chrome Dev Console and Notepad++, was this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Can someone please explain to me what this means? I am not very experienced in JavaScript, so it would also be very, very appreciated if someone could correct it for me! (I've spent hours trying to fix this, and can't seem to get it to work. 
If I'm understanding how the page works, it needs the JavaScript file, with the calculator stuff in it, to run all the calculators.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[The whole page in HTML](http://pastebin.com/gBfn7yMa)

[The calculator.js file](http://pastebin.com/5h4fpuxW)

Comment: Where does the error appear? In which file and in which line?

Comment: Consider spending a couple of hours to learn how to debug JavaScript in the browser. Once you know that, you'll be able to solve such issues in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Sorry, the error appears in the calculator.js file, in line 390.

Comment: Didn't you get tired of typing `document.getElementById("qualify")` so many times?

Comment: @RyanB. Okay, you pass *null* or a non-object variable to *checkEnter()* as the first argument. You have now to find the places where you call this function and to check there for bugs.

Comment: You've made it on [my Google+ wall](https://plus.google.com/107443408698517721118/posts/AcpEpeASzeR) `:P`

Answer (score 2):

In my case

```
document.frms.service_id1.options.add(opt1);
```

form name is frms but my current form name is enquiryfrm  
I put this form name and every think is ok
check all little more variable names or form name

```
document.enquiryfrm.service_id1.options.add(opt1);
```

i solve my problem thank  god!

Answer (score 0):

It means that the variable `value` hasn't been defined and you are using it.

Make sure you have defined `value`.

It would be very helpful if you tell us which line number it's on.

The console will display something like `calculator.js:xx` beside the error where `xx` is the line number.

Answer (score 0):

It actually means that you want to read a property called `value` from an object which is either not an object or *null*!

You can use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/console.log) in order to debug your variable states.

Comment: `variable`? I think it's `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome, and the developer tools are your friend. I believe on Windows, the console is Ctrl+Shift+J.

The console will show you which line the error is on, and if you click on it, will bring you right to the point in the code (most of the time) where the error exists.

"Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" means you are trying to access a value property (likely a DOM element), but the variable is not right. In other words you should find the variable where you are trying to access `.value` and find out why that element isn't showing up.

Comment: `[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[J]` or simpler `[F12]` ;)